# JavaScript called from Objective-c not working anymore

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

Everything is spelled correctly and this has worked before but not sure why not now. ignore that I am putting `text` every where still should work.

```
NSString *theJSMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MagSwipe.loadData('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: theJSMethod];
```

Comment: Is everything that's being passed in being properly escaped?

Comment: have you been trying to debug webview using safari on mac?

Comment: I bet you have an apostrophe (') in one of your strings.

Comment: this is mobile phone gap plugin

Comment: anyway you should be able to see JS errors in safari's console

Comment: yup dont see anything